# Mongoengine - get where the object is referred

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I'm trying out mongoengine in flask (python). And was trying to create a One-to-One field.

I have a model `User` and also models for types of Users like `Author`, `Buyer`, etc. Here's a simple version of my models:

```
class User(db.Document):
    username = db.StringField()
    password = db.StringField()

class Author(db.Document):
    books = db.ListField(db.StringField())
    user = db.ReferenceField(document_type=User, required=True)
```

Now, I can get the user from the author by simply

```
a = author.objects.all()[0] # Or get author through some other method
a.user
```

But if I have a user how do I get the author ?

```
u = user.objects.all()[0]
u.get_author() # ???
```

I know I can do `Author.objects.get(user=u)` but I was wondering if this can be done without an extra query.

Answer (score 2):

Your `User` documents are stored in a separate collection with no reference to the `Author` collection so there is no way to do this without an extra query. You have some options that may make this process easier:

Add an author property to the `User` class:

```
class User(db.Document):
    username = db.StringField()
    password = db.StringField()

    @property
    def author(self):
        return Author.objects(user=self).get()

class Author(db.Document):
    books = db.ListField(db.StringField())
    user = db.ReferenceField(document_type=User, required=True)
```

This will allow you to do:

```
u = User.objects.first()
print(u.author.books)
```

However, it seems that in this context where author is just a special type of `User` then you should use [document inheritance](http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/guide/defining-documents.html?#document-inheritance), for example:

```
class User(db.Document):
    username = db.StringField()
    password = db.StringField()

    meta = {'allow_inheritance': True}

class Author(User):
    books = db.ListField(db.StringField())

a = Author(username="dr_seuss", password="sneech16", 
           books=["Green Eggs and Ham","The Cat in the Hat"])
a.save()
```

This will allow you to query by either `Author` or `User`:

```
>>> Author.objects.first().username
'dr_seuss'

>>> User.objects.first().username
'dr_seuss'
```

Comment: Nice idea about the property ! Sadly there isn't any way to do this without an extra query. (The author user example was a simplified example and in my real case I cannot implement document inheritance.)

Comment: If you are more concerned about read optimisation than write optimisation then you can always store the reference in both documents at the time of writing.